# How to refresh jquery mobile checkboxes theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a list of comboboxes that are dynamically filled from the database.

Html:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="WeekDays">
<fieldset id ="WeekDaysFieldSet" data-role="controlgroup">
```

Javascript:

```
var len = results.rows.length;
$("#WeekDaysFieldSet").empty();
for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    $("#WeekDaysFieldSet").append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+ results.rows.item(i).DayName + '"  CheckboxId="'+results.rows.item(i).id+'" class="custom"/><label for="'+results.rows.item(i).DayName+'" >'+results.rows.item(i).DayName+'</label>'); 
}
```

When I add this line after the function, nothing happens, just all the checkboxes are checked, but the theme isn't added.

```
    $("input[type='checkbox']:first").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Is there a specific place in which I have to add the refreshing line at ?

Comment: Hi i've tried to use var len = 5, and +i+ in the for loop, i've only first checkbox checked, could you explain better the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sort of similar solution:

```
$("#group").append('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">'
    +'<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" /><label for="cb1">text</label>'
    +'<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" /><label for="cb2">More text</label></fieldset>'
    )
    .trigger("create");


$("#check").click(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']:first").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

Check demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/jzGv5/

Comment: This works when the data are statically added, but when I add them dynamically, it don't.

Comment: can you put your data in jsfiddle and send me link?? i will check and let you know if any changes are required.

Comment: I don't know how to choose Jquery mobile in jsfiddle, but here is the code: jsfiddle.net/OnlyHope/kCVzC Thanks.

Comment: I took the same code you wrote & just replaced the variables with the data coming from the db (results.rows.item(i).DayName, results.rows.item(i).id .... )  & that's how it showed up : http://s17.postimage.org/xmuwdr8xp/Checkboxes_problem.png

Comment: IT Worked NOW !! I just made  var.s &  assigned the data coming from db before adding them to the string .. 
Thanks you soooooo Much,,,, your answer is really helpful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use add new class to apply the new class

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:first").attr("checked",true).addClass('refresh');
```

Comment: Do you know where should I write this line ?